# Better approach for searching in data using JS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

If I have a JSON file contain **huge** data looks like this

```
    {
                  "completed": true,
                  "completions": [
                    {
                  "id": 123,
                  "lead_time": 111,
                  "result": [
                    {

                      "id": "FQAWeIOlNO",
                      "value": {
                        "text": "some text for test"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "data": {
                "url": "www.example.com/1_123_4.wav"
              },
              "id": 123
       }
```

my code be like something like this:

```
arr.forEach((obj) => { //arr contains all the data from JSON

  id = obj.id
  let repeated = obj.data.url.replace('www.example.com/', '').split('.wav')
  fileName = repeated[0]
// here i want to make the search.
    }
```

so I'm accessing the url part through a forEach loop and fetching the **filenName.wav** .

I want to walk through all the URLs and check if there exists the another URL with the same **.wav** name or not
so for every time i have to take one .wav from the URL and loop through all the other URLS, this will takes time O(N^2) which will be time consuming as I have too much data.

I found that I can use Objects to do this approach and search within them, but i couldn't understand how will they work, or how I will search in them. As I understand Objects always get overridden so I want get use of them that much (I don't know if this correct).

If someone know better approach, It would be more than welcome and if someone can guide me if Objects is the solution that I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result can be achieved with time O(n) using objects, use filename as key and array in value. While looping check the object if the key exists; if it does, push the url to the array.

```js
let arr = [
    {
      "completed": true,
      "completions": [{
        "id": 123,
        "lead_time": 111,
        "result": [{

          "id": "FQAWeIOlNO",
          "value": {
            "text": "some text for test"
          }
        }]
      }],
      "data": {
        "url": "www.example.com/1_123_4.wav"
      },
      "id": 123
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "completions": [{
        "id": 124,
        "lead_time": 111,
        "result": [{

          "id": "FQAWeIOlNO",
          "value": {
            "text": "some text for test"
          }
        }]
      }],
      "data": {
        "url": "www.example1.com/1_123_4.wav"
      },
      "id": 124
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "completions": [{
        "id": 125,
        "lead_time": 111,
        "result": [{

          "id": "FQAWeIOlNO",
          "value": {
            "text": "some text for test"
          }
        }]
      }],
      "data": {
        "url": "www.example.com/123_4.wav"
      },
      "id": 125
    }
]

let segregateByFile = arr.reduce((obj,rec) => {
        let url = rec.data.url
        let urlSplit = url.split('/')
        let fileName = urlSplit[urlSplit.length - 1]
        obj[fileName] = obj[fileName] || []
        obj[fileName].push(url)
        return obj
      },{})
      
console.log(segregateByFile)
```

the above code will return an object with filename as key and value as array of url. You can check how many times a file is repeated by checking the length and easily iterate over the array to check the url the file repeats in